# asp.net json copy data from table to another table

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, json, asp.net-mvc

I'am trying to copy data from 'bareme' table to 'affiche' table then I will retrieve data from table 'affiche'

```
    public class db
{
    MySqlConnection DefaultConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);


    public DataSet enter()
    {
        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO affiche (nivJauge,qte_cons) select * from bareme", DefaultConnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(com);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds); //the ERROR appears here
        return ds;
    }
```

}

```
database_Access_Layer.db dblayer = new database_Access_Layer.db();
    public ActionResult affiche()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult get_data()
    {
        DataSet ds = dblayer.enter();
        List<jauge> listjauge = new List<jauge>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            listjauge.Add(new jauge
            {
                nivJauge = Convert.ToDouble(dr["nivJauge"]),
                qte_cons = Convert.ToDouble(dr["qte_cons"]),
            });
        }
        return Json(listjauge, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }




   <script>
    $(function () {
        $.get("get_data", {}, function (data) {
            var row;
            $.each(data, function (i, v1) {
                row += "<tr><td>" + v1.nivJauge+ "</td><td>" + v1.qte_cons+ "</td></tr>"
            });
            $("#tbldata").append(row);
    })
    })
</script>
```

and while debugging this problem appears in the line "da.Fill(ds)"

Error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'qte_cons' in 'field list''

Comment: Can you please expand on the problem you're having and any errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your problem is with

```
    INSERT INTO affiche (nivJauge,qte_cons) select * from bareme
```

use the column names for select statement. it should be something like this

```
    INSERT INTO affiche (nivJauge,qte_cons) select first_column_name, second_column_name from bareme
```